# Is there a way to do a selective sum using a time interval in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, the first table has columns: id, start_time, and end_time. The second table has columns: id, timestamp, value. Is there a way to make a sum of table 2 based on the conditions in table 1?

Table 1:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2000-01-01 01:00:00 | 2000-01-05 02:45:00 |
| 5 | 2000-01-10 01:00:00 | 2000-01-15 02:45:00 |
| 6 | 2000-01-01 01:00:00 | 2000-01-05 02:45:00 |
| 6 | 2000-01-11 01:00:00 | 2000-01-12 02:45:00 |
| 6 | 2000-01-15 01:00:00 | 2000-01-20 02:45:00 |

Table 2:

| id | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2000-01-01 05:00:00 | 1 |
| 5 | 2000-01-01 06:00:00 | 2 |
| 6 | 2000-01-01 05:00:00 | 1 |
| 6 | 2000-01-11 05:00:00 | 2 |
| 6 | 2000-01-15 05:00:00 | 2 |
| 6 | 2000-01-15 05:30:00 | 2 |

Desired result:

| id | start_date | end_date | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2000-01-01 01:00:00 | 2000-01-05 02:45:00 | 3 |
| 5 | 2000-01-10 01:00:00 | 2000-01-15 02:45:00 | null |
| 6 | 2000-01-01 01:00:00 | 2000-01-05 02:45:00 | 1 |
| 6 | 2000-01-11 01:00:00 | 2000-01-12 02:45:00 | 2 |
| 6 | 2000-01-15 01:00:00 | 2000-01-20 02:45:00 | 4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT a.id, a.start_date, a.end_date, sum(b.value) AS sum
  FROM table1 AS a
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS b
    ON b.id = a.id
   AND b.timestamp >= a.start_date
   AND b.timestamp < a.end_date
 GROUP BY a.id, a.start_date, a.end_date
```